# Prove that for any $a,b \in \mathbf{R}$, $\left(\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx\right)^{2}\geq (b-a)^{2}+(f(b)-f(a))^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, inequality

Let $f : \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Prove that for any $a,b \in \mathbf{R}$, $$\left(\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx\right)^{2}\geq (b-a)^{2}+(f(b)-f(a))^{2}$$.

**My Attempt**: Using mean value theorem I deducd that for some $c\in(a,b)$ $$\left(\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+f'(c)^{2}}dx\right)^{2}\geq (b-a)^{2}+(f(b)-f(a))^{2}$$. Give hints to complete this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, think triangles.

The LHS of the equation is the arc length squared. On a right triangle this would be a hypotenuse. Otherwise it would be longer still since the shortest distance between two points is a straight line.

RHS are the two legs of the triangle squared.

$c^2 \geq a^2 + b^2$

Comment: Thanks, Now it is clear.